# How to transform my data frame to make rows columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, transpose, csplit

I have a data frame with two columns, "Type" and "Stats". I want to each type to have one row with all of the stats in a separate column. For example, my data frame looks something like this:

```
Column Type has values: A A A A B B B B
Column Stats has values:15 2 73 12 12 6 52 17
```

And I want it to look like:

```
Column Type has values: A B
Column Stat1 has values: 15 12
Column Stat2 has values: 2 6
Column Stat3 has values: 73 52
Column Stat4 has values: 12 17
```

Not all types have the same number of stats, some types are missing a stat value and others have extra. I tried using t(), but ran into issues. I then tried to combine all the values of Stat into one column and separate with `gsub()` and `csplit()`, but I had issues combining all the Stat values for each type into one column. Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_wider` after creating a sequence column grouped by 'Type'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Type) %>%
   mutate(rn = str_c('Stats_', row_number())) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = Stats)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Type  Stats_1 Stats_2 Stats_3 Stats_4
#  <fct>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 A          15       2      73      12
#2 B          12       6      52      17
```

---

Or using `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Type ~ paste0("Stats_", rowid(Type)),  value.var = 'Stats')
```

---

Or as @Onyambu suggested in `base R`, it can be done with `reshape`

```
reshape(transform(df1, time = ave(Stats, Type,
           FUN = seq_along)), dir="wide", idvar = "Type", sep = "_")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Type = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 4), 
         Stats = c(15, 2, 73, 12, 12, 6, 52, 17))
```

Comment: you could also add `reshape(transform(df1,time = ave(Stats,Type,FUN = seq_along)),dir="wide",idvar = "Type",sep = "_")` from base R